# Access an attribute through Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get the ID of a house related to a user but I get the famous *Trying to get property of non-object* error.

In my **index.blade.php** I use

```
{{ $user->house->id }}
```

**User.php**

```
public function house()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\House');
}
```

**House.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: It looks your relation is wrong. Show your table structure we may help.

Comment: Does the `User` *actually* have a `House` record? Are you using `User::with(["house"])...`? What happens if you do `dd($user->house)`? What happens if you do `dd($user->house()->first());`? Lots more info needed here :P

Comment: BTW one of your relations must be `belongsTo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the user has house object. Try this:

```
@if ($user->house)

 {{ $user->house->id }}

@endif
```

Comment: That was about it, the if! Thank you